# Allow my Android view to be embedded in other apps

Tags: java, android

In web-based development and Windows-based development it is possible to develop applets or components that other applications can embed in their own UI seamlessly. I have a component (derived from `View`) that does some real-time animation that I'd like other apps to be able to embed in their own views or activities. Is it possible to allow other apps to embed this component in them in such a way that, when my app is updated, the other apps will automatically exhibit the updated behavior in their embedded component?

If this is possible, I'm having a hard time figuring out the search terms to use to look up how to do this. How would one app go about embedding a view from another app, and what happens if that other app isn't installed?

Comment: Nope, you only option AFAIK is to make your component in a library project. Then other developers can reference your Library project when creating their own apps. This will let them use your View, but it won't be able to magically update itself, it would be up to them to update your library project if they wanted to use newer features/behaviour.

Comment: While this will not solve your specific problem, it is possible to publish a UI that can be embedded in other apps, by means of publishing `RemoteViews`, the same as you do for app widgets, rich notifications, etc. This directory has a pair of sample apps demonstrating this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RemoteViews  However, `RemoteViews` does not work with custom `View` classes, only the stock ones (and really only a subset of those).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly allow embeding in the way of an iframe.

However, you could make your View a library project that other developers can include in their app, much like they include another company's SDK. To allow updating automatically, you will need to have your app installed in addition to theirs, and when making the library project, you will have to make a BroadcastReceiver that can react to broadcasts you send from your app to update the Views in other apps.

Your SDK can then receive these Broadcasts, and update your View accordingly.

Comment: Has this ever been done in practice? Any examples of apps doing this -- notifying other Apps of an update? Does the app receiving the notification have to be re-compiled, or is there some way it can automatically download an updated encapsulated component?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I have never seen this done so far, but it should in theory be possible. However, if you update your View component's source code, your third party users will have to recompile their app with an updated library project.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of being a BroadcastReceiver if the app needs to be recompiled when it receives notification that an update exists. That's not something that can be done automatically, but it's an interesting tip to remember that might come into play somehow.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN You don't need to recompile if only the content of the View has changed. In that case, you can pass the new data based on which the View is drawn using a BroadcastReceiver, and the receiving app can take the new data and redraw the View. You only need to recompile if you change the code which the View uses to draw its content.

Comment: I see; now that I think about it, if I wanted to always maintain the content in my app I could accomplish something similar by having the other app (the library version of my code) always refer to content in my app via ContentProvider instead of always expecting it to be embedded. And only if the ContentProvider is not available, defer to data embedded in the library. Is there an easy way to determine whether my ContentProvider exists on the device, or is there a better way to do this (is BroadcastReceiver better)?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN ContentProvider vs. BroadcastReceiver would be like server polling vs server push. If you use a CP, the app will only update the View when it wants. If you use a BR that is part of your library, you can send updates to the other app when you want to. I haven't really had to check if a CP exists, so I can't say if it is possible, but your idea of using the CP and default data sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your current project as Library project. You add the Library project to the project you want use the custom `View`. Your custom `View` will be accessible in that project.

You can mark a project as Library project by going to Project Properties > Android and checking the appropriate checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app widget for your application, and that widget can be used by any application that acts as a widget host - which few do - but at least you could have it on your home screen. I wonder why this is not done more - that would be a killer feature for many applications.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Gives more information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your answer, however, please refrain from leaving links as the substance of the answer; leave a snippet of code for reference. Links can easily become invalid if the URL is changed.